# Saving sender reference in Actor field

Tags: java, akka

I am novice to Akka and I will be very glad is someone with Akka experience could help me. I read following article http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.1/java/untyped-actors.html and part with title "Lifecycle Monitoring aka DeathWatch" contains following example:

```
public class WatchActor extends UntypedActor {
  final ActorRef child = this.getContext().actorOf(Props.empty(), "child");
  {
    this.getContext().watch(child); // <-- the only call needed for registration
  }
  ActorRef lastSender = getContext().system().deadLetters();

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Object message) {
    if (message.equals("kill")) {
      getContext().stop(child);
      lastSender = getSender();
    } else if (message instanceof Terminated) {
      final Terminated t = (Terminated) message;
      if (t.getActor() == child) {
        lastSender.tell("finished", getSelf());
      }
    } else {
      unhandled(message);
    }
  }
}
```

For me is not clear why we could save sender ref in actor field lastSender. For example we could have following situation: actor A send kill message to WatchActor, we save in WatchActor lastSender field reference of actor A, then actor B send kill message to WatchActor, we save in WatchActor lastSender field reference of actor B, Watch actor receiver Terminated message from child actor and answer to actor B, but actor A will not receive answer. Is this code incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

What you describe could happen is correct, so the example is not entirely safe and could have unexpected outcome if multiple actors would send the "kill" message to `WatchActor`. The example in the docs could probably be improved in this regard.

It is annoying but maybe not super relevant to the section of the docs, which essentially describes how an actor will receive `Terminated` once another actor it watches has been stopped and that it happens asynchronously.

Please file a ticket here if you think it is important enough: https://github.com/akka/akka/issues